Invalid magic number. Expected 0xa1 and received 0x48
I'm trying to setup Keycloak to use Infinispan. Here's my configuration.
Both Keycloak and Infinispan are on a single ECS cluster but different services.
Using a load balancer and hence https://myapp.com points to keycloak and http://myapp.com:11222 points to infinispan.
Whenever I use myapp.com as hostname in cache-ispn.xml on keycloak, I end up getting this error
2024-11-24 16:27:25,743 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ISPN004003: Invalid magic number. Expected 0xa1 and received 0x48

But if I use internal/public IP of the ECS task, then this works as expected.
I'm not able to figure out what the problem is with using myapp.com instead of the IP.
Here's my keycloak cache-ispn.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd"
        xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0">
    <cache-container name="keycloak">
        <!-- cluster-name: globalCluster -->
        <transport cluster="${infinispan.cluster.name:globalCluster}"  stack="tcp" lock-timeout="60000" site="site1"/>
        <local-cache name="generalCache">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="sessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="realms">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="users">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="authorization">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <local-cache name="keys">
            <encoding>
                <key media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
                <value media-type="application/x-java-object"/>
            </encoding>
            <expiration max-idle="3600000"/>
            <memory max-count="1000"/>
        </local-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="sessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="sessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="authenticationSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="offlineSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="clientSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="offlineClientSessions"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures" owners="2">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="loginFailures"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens" owners="2">
            <expiration max-idle="-1" interval="300000"/>
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="actionTokens"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </distributed-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="work">
            <remote-store xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:store:remote:15.0"
                          cache="work"
                          purge="false"
                          preload="false"
                          segmented="false"
                          shared="true"
                          raw-values="true"
                          >
                <remote-server host="myapp.com" port="${infinispan.bind.port:11222}" />
                <security>
                    <authentication server-name="infinispan">
                        <digest username="adminuser" password="password" realm="default"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security>
            </remote-store>
        </replicated-cache>
    </cache-container>
</infinispan>

And here is infinispan.xml file from Infinispan deployment.
<infinispan
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:15.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-15.0.xsd
                            urn:infinispan:server:15.0 https://infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-server-15.0.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:15.0"
      xmlns:server="urn:infinispan:server:15.0">
    <jgroups>
        <stack name="jdbc-ping-tcp" extends="tcp">
            <JDBC_PING connection_driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
                     connection_username="admin" connection_password="password"
                     connection_url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/infinispan"
                     initialize_sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS JGROUPSPING (own_addr varchar(200) NOT NULL, cluster_name varchar(200) NOT NULL, ping_data BINARY(124), constraint PK_JGROUPSPING PRIMARY KEY (own_addr, cluster_name));"
                     info_writer_sleep_time="500"
                     remove_all_data_on_view_change="true"
                     stack.combine="REPLACE"
                     stack.position="MPING" />
        </stack>
    </jgroups>
    <cache-container name="remoteKeycloak" statistics="true">
        <transport cluster="globalCluster" stack="jdbc-ping-tcp" node-name="mainNode" site="site1"/>
        <serialization marshaller="org.infinispan.jboss.marshalling.commons.GenericJBossMarshaller">
            <allow-list>
                <class>org.*</class>
                <regex>.*</regex>
            </allow-list>
        </serialization>
        <security>
            <authorization/>
        </security>
        <local-cache name="generalCache">
            <expiration lifespan="6000000"/>
            <memory max-count="10000"/>
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </local-cache>
        <replicated-cache name="work">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </replicated-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="sessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="authenticationSessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="clientSessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineSessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="offlineClientSessions">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="actionTokens">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
        <distributed-cache name="loginFailures">
            <encoding media-type="application/x-protostream"/>
        </distributed-cache>
    </cache-container>
    <server xmlns="urn:infinispan:server:15.0">
        <interfaces>
            <interface name="public">
                <inet-address value="0.0.0.0"/>
            </interface>
        </interfaces>
        <socket-bindings default-interface="public" port-offset="0">
            <socket-binding name="default" port="11222"/>
            <socket-binding name="memcached" port="11221"/>
        </socket-bindings>
        <security>
            <credential-stores>
                <credential-store name="credentials" path="credentials.pfx">
                    <clear-text-credential clear-text="secret"/>
                </credential-store>
            </credential-stores>
            <security-realms>
                <security-realm name="default">
                    <properties-realm groups-attribute="Roles">
                        <user-properties path="users.properties"/>
                        <group-properties path="groups.properties"/>
                    </properties-realm>
                </security-realm>
            </security-realms>
        </security>
        <endpoints socket-binding="default" security-realm="default">
            <endpoint>
                <hotrod-connector name="hotrod">
                    <authentication>
                        <sasl mechanisms="DIGEST-MD5" server-name="infinispan" />
                    </authentication>
                </hotrod-connector>
                <rest-connector name="rest"/>
            </endpoint>
        </endpoints>
    </server>
</infinispan>


It seems the Hot Rod data stream is being modified. The load balancer behind myapp.com must handle HTTP and Hot Rod traffic. Are you sure it can do that? Unrelated to the issue, and If it is a new project, I would advise you to use KC26; it does not use GenericJBossMarshaller and deprecates support for remote stores. You will have a bad time upgrading to KC 26.

Loadbalancer is listening for 11222 port. Do I need to make it listen to other ports as well ? If so, what should they be forwarded to in infinispan

Try adding <property name="infinispan.client.hotrod.client_intelligence">BASIC</property> inside the <remote-store> tag. It may hurt the response time but it should play nice with load balancers.

Tried the property tag, still got the same error

I have no clue then. The easiest fix is to use the internal IP as the Hot Rod client has its load balancer. Otherwise, we need to capture the traffic from the load balancer to ensure it isn't modifying the data stream in any way.
